# How to display different mysql table using dropdown list in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I have different tables like table 1 to 5 in mysql database. I want a code for displaying each table when i select it from drop down table list. when i try to execute the below i got no response and no data loaded form the sql.

```
<div> 
<form action="table1.php" method="GET">
<input list="name" name="name">
<datalist id="name">
    <option value="table 1">
    <option value="table 2">
    <option value="table 3">
    <option value="table 4">
    <option value="table 5">
</datalist>
<input type="submit" name="search" value="search">
</form>
</div>

<div>
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
        <th>Column 4</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

in the php code i assign a variable for the selection value and given in the program. but i got a error that the variable is undefined or not be used in the $conn statement.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "sheet";
$tbname= $_GET['name'];

if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM '$tbname'");
        $stmt->execute();

        $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>".$result['Column 1']."</th>";
        echo "<th>".$result['Column 2']."</th>";
        echo "<th>".$result['Column 3']."</th>";
        echo "<th>".$result['Column 4']."</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $conn = null;
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: Try just `"SELECT * FROM $tbname"` you don't quote table names.

Comment: Also you better check your input matches a known table name before you try sending it to your database.

Comment: why are you using get and not post if it is going from a local html file to a local php file?

Comment: I have checked the inputs. there is no response in the page. not even showing any errors.

Comment: hi Gert. I have tried post method and also get method. no responses in both .

Comment: i see the problem now i will post a answer for you soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this code will helps you,

I have slightly changed your code structure and added `fetchAll()` method to retrieve the rows from db, you can use `fetch()` method also to fetch row by row And finally I'm printing those rows at the end.

```
<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "sheet";
$tbname= $_GET['name'];
$results = array();

if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `$tbname`");
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll();//Add this line to get db results

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $conn = null;
}
?>

<div> 
    <form action="table1.php" method="GET">
        <input list="name" name="name">
        <datalist id="name">
            <option value="table 1">
            <option value="table 2">
            <option value="table 3">
        </datalist>
        <input type="submit" name="search" value="search">
    </form>
</div>

<div>
    <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
            <th>Column 4</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        if (is_array($results) && count($results)>0) {
            foreach ($results as $result) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$result['Column 1']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$result['Column 2']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$result['Column 3']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$result['Column 4']."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
        ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have placed table name in single quotation which is incorrect, you need to use backticks instead.

The following line in your PHP code is wrong

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM '$tbname'");
```

It should be changed to this

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `$tbname`");
```

Comment: Thank you Joshi. But still i get no response or no data loaded from database.

Comment: Do you get any sql error when you run sql query ? please check it and also make sure database connection settings proper and those table has data in them

Answer (score 1):

All you've done here is set the fetch mode, you didn't actually fetch anything.

change:

```
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>".$result['Column 1']."</th>";
echo "<th>".$result['Column 2']."</th>";
echo "<th>".$result['Column 3']."</th>";
echo "<th>".$result['Column 4']."</th>";
echo "</tr>";
```

to:

```
while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<th>".$result['Column 1']."</th>";
     echo "<th>".$result['Column 2']."</th>";
     echo "<th>".$result['Column 3']."</th>";
     echo "<th>".$result['Column 4']."</th>";
     echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you Augwa, I got the following error

 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'catch' (T_CATCH) in C:\wamp64\www\sample\table1.php on line 74

Comment: you left out the trailing } brace that was already there. after the closing brace of `while () { ... }` you need to have another one.

Comment: Proper formatting of your code will help prevent problems like that. I edited your question to properly format your php code.

Comment: Thank you Augwa, now i get the data . thank you for the help.